# How to get the value of an EditorFor JavaScript ASP

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want to get the value of an EditorFor in ASP but it returns me nothing.

Thank you for your helps

```
<div class="form-group" id="ParticipantNumber">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ParticipantNumber, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2"})
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ParticipantNumber, new { @class = "ParticipantNumber", disabled = "disabled" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ParticipantNumber)
    </div>
</div>
```

My JavaScript code

```
$('#ParticipantNumber').keyup(function () {
    var s = $('#ParticipantNumber').val();
    console.log(s)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JavaScript is looking for `$('#ParticipantNumber')`, which is the element with the ID `ParticipantNumber`. Your code defines the editor with:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ParticipantNumber, new {
                          @class = "ParticipantNumber", disabled = "disabled" })
```

The intention here is to assign the `input` with the class `ParticipantNumber`, which would have meant you could address it with `$('.ParticipantNumber') instead.

*However*, the parameter you're using is `additionalViewData`; the `EditorFor` HTML editor does not have a property to reflect HTML properties back into the renderer. Your two options are:

1. Write a custom template
2. Change the way you're referencing the `input`

Option 1 is possibly a bit over-the-top for your needs; with option 2, the following will solve your problem, by simply referencing the `input` within your `<div id='ParticipantNumber'>`:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ParticipantNumber)

$('#ParticipantNumber input').keyup(function () {
    var s = $(this).val();
    console.log(s)
}
```

Comment: `$('input.ParticipantNumber').keyup(function () {}` like that ? But it returns nothing

Comment: That should do it, yes.

Comment: It returns nothing my friend

Comment: Have you changed it within the function too - `$('input.ParticipantNumber').val();` ?

Comment: (You can also use `$(this).val()`, as `this` is the current event's source object.)

Comment: it doesn't enter in the method my friend

Comment: @user3524214 Can you post the HTML being output? It might be wrapping the input  with a div - I can't recall the exact format that it gives offhand.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late coming to this party but I recently had this issue with Html.EditorFor.

What fixed it for me was to simply switch to TextBoxFor. So instead of:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ParticipantNumber, new { @class = "ParticipantNumber", disabled = "disabled", id="ParticipantNumber" })
```

Change it to:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ParticipantNumber, new { @class = "ParticipantNumber", disabled = "disabled", id="ParticipantNumber" })
```

Answer (score -1):

In the javascript, you are querying for the "id" attribute, but `@Html.EditorFor` does not emit any id by default. You can modify your code like this

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ParticipantNumber, new { @class = "ParticipantNumber", disabled = "disabled", id="ParticipantNumber" })
```

Then your javascript will work.

Comment: There is already an element with the ID `ParticipantNumber` in the DOM.